# How to make my relation work

Tags: prolog

I have the following relation: index(X,N,List).

for example:

```
index(X,2,[a,b,c]).
X=b

index(b,N,[a,b,c]).
N=2
```

I don't know how to make my relation to work with the second example. It says that N is not defined well
Here is my code (it works well for the first example).

```
index(X,1,[X|_]).
index(X,N,[_|Tail]) :- N > 1, N1 is N - 1 , index(X,N1,Tail).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a SWI-Prolog built-in `nth1/3` that does what you want:

```
?- nth1(N, [a, b, c], b).
N = 2 ;
false.
```

Look at its source code:

```
?- listing(nth1).
lists:nth1(A, C, D) :-
    integer(A), !,
    B is A+ -1,
    nth0_det(B, C, D).
lists:nth1(A, B, C) :-
    var(A), !,
    nth_gen(B, C, 1, A).

true.

?- listing(nth0_det).
lists:nth0_det(0, [A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(1, [_, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(2, [_, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(3, [_, _, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(4, [_, _, _, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(5, [_, _, _, _, _, A|_], A) :- !.
lists:nth0_det(A, [_, _, _, _, _, _|C], D) :-
    B is A+ -6,
    B>=0,
    nth0_det(B, C, D).

true.

?- listing(nth_gen).
lists:nth_gen([A|_], A, B, B).
lists:nth_gen([_|B], C, A, E) :-
    succ(A, D),
    nth_gen(B, C, D, E).

true.
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `N` has not been instantiated to a numeric type when Prolog attempts to evaluate the goals `N > 1` and `N1 is N - 1` in the recursive clause defining `index/3`. This causes the instantiation error you are reporting.

I don't know how to solve your problem directly, but I have two suggestions. The first is to use an accumulator, so that the arithmetic operations in the recursive clause can be evaluated:

```
get(M,Xs,X) :- get(1,M,Xs,X).
get(N,N,[X|_],X).
get(N,M,[_|Xs],X) :-
  L is N + 1,
  get(L,M,Xs,X).
```

For instance:

```
?- index(N,[a,b],X).
   N = 1,
   X = a ;
   N = 2,
   X = b ;
   false.
```

The other is to use a natural number type, so that the index can be constructed *via* unification:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(N)) :- nat(N).

get(s(0),[X|_],X).
get(s(N),[_|Y],X) :- get(N,Y,X).
```

For instance,

```
?- get(N,[a,b],X).
   N = s(0),
   X = a ;
   N = s(s(0)),
   X = b ;
   false.
```

Hopefully this was helpful. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable will come along and give a better solution.

Comment: thanks , the solution i've found is easier ... the second line is: index(X,N,[_|Tail]) :- index(X,N1,Tail), N is N1 + 1.